# Gdb Buffer Overflow; Python won't execute

Tags: python, gdb, buffer, overflow, buffer-overflow

I have a problem with gdb, I cant make a python command run inside. It just hangs forever until i press enter a second time.

```
gdb$  run $(python -c "print('A'*50)");
Starting program: /home/Myprogram $(python -c "print('A'*50)");


[buf]: 

[check] 0x4030201
[Inferior 1 (process 27229) exited normally]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------[regs]
  EAX:Error while running hook_stop:
No registers.
```

I went searching and each time someone uses this same command :

```
Starting program: /home/Myprogram $(python -c "print('A'*50)");
```

They have a line 50 'A's just below.

the second part (after [buf] : ) is only shown if i press enter a second time. If i do nothing it just hangs and doesn't execute python.

Any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution :

```
echo "your python code" > bla.py
python bla.py > output
gdb yourProgram
```

In gdb :

```
gdb$ run < output
```